# jenkins pipeline readYaml how to use variable to specify key

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Suppose the yaml file is like this：

```
#test.yaml
0.6.5.1.0:
  module:
  - mysql
  - zk

0.7.1.0.0:
  module:
  - java
```

Now I want to get the module list of specified version, and the version is a variable, I try to write the jenkins pipeline like this:

```
yamlFile = readYaml file: test.yaml
version = '0.7.1.0.0'
moduleList = yamlFile.get("${version}").get(module)
```

but this can't work, yamlFile.get("${version}") is a null object, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('read') {
            steps {
                script {
                     def data = readYaml text: """
0.6.5.1.0:
  module:
  - mysql
  - zk

0.7.1.0.0:
  module:
  - java
  """
                   version = '0.7.1.0.0'
                   println data.get(version).get('module')
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on server in /home/user/workspace/task
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (read)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] echo
[java]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me when I try to use it with toString() method. Here's my code

`envid = "dev"
  println(envid) //this is printing the app envid for example dev here 
  datas = readYaml ( file: 'dev.yml')
   id = datas.dev.id.toString() /it's working and picking
  name = datas.get(envid).name.toString() // this is not working
`                              and dev.yml looks like      
`
dev:
  id: 1
  name: test.      `
any suggestions here? @MaratC

Comment: if you ever get stucked into situation like mine where it does not work this way then check the type of the variable and convert it to string so that the get function can take it so my solution was to convert envid = var.toString() which resolved my problem.